# How to delete a word from a String in Java?

Tags: java

How to delete a word from a string? E.g if I have following inputs:

```
Cancer is a fatal disease

Cancer is afataldisease

Cancer is a fataldisease

Cancer is afataldisease

Cancer is a     fatal     disease

Cancer is     afataldisease

Cancer is a     fataldisease

Cancer is     afataldisease
```

And output should be:

```
Cancer is a disease(for first 4 cases)
```

And for remaining:

```
Cancer is a           disease

Cancer is     a disease

Cancer is a      disease

Cancer is     a disease
```

I have desired output for first 4 cases but not the last 4 above. In last 4 cases, extra spaces are left after removal of word.

```
String deleteWord(String sentence,String... words)
{
    for(String s:words)
    {
        sentence=sentence.replaceAll(s," ");
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with using  `String.replaceAll("word"," ")` method.

Comment: use some regex (`\\s` to match spaces)

Comment: @OmarAhmed It gives redundant spaces for last 4 cases above

Comment: @RC What would be such regex which would work for unknown number of spaces?

Comment: see @karna answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my code to match your query .I initially misunderstood what you needed for nonconsecutive spaces now this code saves the format of each single token of your word (its outer left,right index and an integer to tell weather the spaces are consecutive)in an integer ArrayList and according to that data the sentence is modified.So now it works if repeated ,at start or at end.Even if the 2 types of sentences that you mentioned are in one sentence.

```
String sentence= " fatal Cancer is a fatal diseasefatal";//one example
String word="fatal";

int spaces=0;
int left=-1;
int right=0;
int nonspacechar=0;//leftmost nonspacechar
int difference=0;//difference between the outermost indexes
int consecspaces=0;

ArrayList<Integer> format = new ArrayList();//declare arrayList

for(int i =0;i<sentence.length();i++){


if(i==sentence.indexOf(word,right)){//to get the left index after the word's right index

    if(nonspacechar==0){
        left=nonspacechar;
    }else
left=nonspacechar+1;

format.add(left);//adding the left index to the arraylist
if(sentence.length()-i==word.length()){//if the word is at the end
   right=i+word.length();
format.add(right);


     format.add(2); 
break;
}


i=i+word.length()-1;

continue;
}

if(sentence.charAt(i)!=' '){
    if(left>=0){//to get the right non space index when left is set
right=i;
format.add(right);//add right outermost index

if(i==sentence.length()-1&&sentence.charAt(i)=='.'){
        format.add(2);
    }else

if(spaces>1){
    format.add(1);

}else if(nonspacechar==0){
       format.add(2); 
}else
     format.add(0);



        left=-1;//reset left

}
nonspacechar=i;
    spaces=0;
}else if(left>=0&&spaces==1){
spaces=0;
}else
spaces++; 
}


int k=0;
StringBuilder newSentence=new StringBuilder(sentence);//declare the newsentence Stringbuilder to be replaced acording to indexes

while(k<format.size()){

    left=format.get(k);
    right=format.get(k+1);


    if(k>0){
        if(consecspaces==1){//check last consecuative space condition

        left=left-difference;
        right=right-difference; 
        }else{
          left=left-(difference);//subtract last difference
        right=right-(difference);  
        }
    }

     consecspaces=format.get(k+2);




if(consecspaces==1){//check if consecuativespaces exist
  difference=difference+word.length();//adding word on difference
 newSentence=newSentence.replace(newSentence.indexOf(word,left),newSentence.indexOf(word,left)+word.length(),"");

}else if(consecspaces==2){ 
      difference=difference+(right-left);
      newSentence=newSentence.replace(left,right,"");
}else{
     difference=difference+(right-left)-1; //adding word on difference
     newSentence=newSentence.replace(left,right," ");
}
k=k+3;
}

sentence=new String(newSentence);//get the new sentence
    System.out.print(sentence);

}


}
```

Of course to replace a string according to indexes I had to use a StringBuilder also don't forget to import Arraylist:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Note: this algorithm doesn't work if the word is consecuatively repeated which Iam sure isn't grammer :).

Comment: This does not work for first 4 cases. The word should be always removed despite of the number of spaces(if any) around it.

Comment: After a modification it partially works. However it does not remove "fatal" if it appears twice. And it duplicates string if "fatal" is present at end!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in these cases?.For the last 4 cases spaces are left but word removed.I 've tested it thoroughly make sure all the code is copied.

Comment: Just like @karna's answer, if the input is "Cancer is a diseasefatal", its output is "Cancer is a disease " (new space inserted at end) and if input is "Fatalcancer is a disease", its output is " cancer is a disease " (new space inserted at start)!

Comment: you'r right I added a condition to solve that problem.It should work now.

Comment: "fatalCancer is a fatal diseasefatal." still gives a space at end: "Cancer is a disease ."

Comment: Thats because you added a dot at end your question is pretty specific but no problem I've added another condition for that too and now it should work.

Comment: Without adding dot, space still appeared and I added dot so that you could see it more clearly. Anyhow it works correctly now and I have accepted your answer. I have added support for more punctuation by adding ||sentence.charAt(i)=='!' etc. in the condition. However, it looks like I will have to add plenty of conditions for digits from 0-9 as well, unless a regex can take care of it.

Comment: Just so you know how it works in that regard .If the word is exactly between 2 chars or has 1 space before it or/and 1 space after it ,the word including these spaces if they exist is removed and a space is added. Thats why you saw space before the dot as the word was exactly between 2 chars.

Comment: There was still a problem with " fatal Cancer is a fatal diseasefatal"a space was inserted at start and with "Cancer is a fatal disease fatal" space inserted at end. I had just fixed that by adding a third format .Now you can consider the answer accepted :).

Answer (score 4):

You should replace the word fatal with space. After that check for multiple regular spaces in each sentence. If you have multiple regular spaces then replace it with single space.

```
public class ReplaceWord {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str = {
"Cancer is a fatal disease",

"Cancer is afataldisease",

"Cancer is a fataldisease",

"Cancer is afataldisease",

"Cancer is a     fatal     disease",

"Cancer is     afataldisease",

"Cancer is a     fataldisease",

"Cancer is     afataldisease"};



    for(String string: str) {
        string = string.replace("fatal", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        System.out.println(string);

    }



    }}
```

The regex **"\\s+"** will check for multiple regular spaces. If found, it gets replaced with single space.

Comment: It's intuitive but I want to conserve spaces in input so not the solution

Comment: What do you mean by conserve spaces in input? If you don't want to modify the input then you can create a new array, and in the new array you can put the new values.

Comment: By conserving spaces, I mean that e.g. in "Cancer is a     fatal     disease",I want it to be "Cancer is a           disease" instead of "Cancer is a disease". I don't want to remove multiple consecutive spaces if they are present in string.

Comment: If the input is "Cancer is a diseasefatal", its output is "Cancer is a disease " (new space inserted at end) and if input is "fatalcancer is a disease", its output is " cancer is a disease " (new space inserted at start)!

Answer (score 0):

After replacing a word "fatal" with single space,

Try to split the whole string with a single space (" ") and then while iterating the returned string array remove the single space elements and merge back the words with a single space in it. So with this unwanted spaces would be removed.

Comment: Spaces are not unwanted